# Is there any way to use Mongodb to store images using express as a backend, and show that data in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, vue.js, mongoose

I want to create kind of an photo gallery like application. It works fine if file system is used, but when using Mongodb I am facing problems. I tried using base64 way to store image data to a server and retrieve it. it works fine in .ejs file but not in Vue. Finally I just want to upload an image and retrieve it and make it visible as a image in Vue component but could not find any method. If you have any way please help me, thanks in advance.

Express Side Code:

```js
app.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
    const obj = {
        img: { 
            data: 'data:image/png;base64,' + (fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.file.filename))).toString("base64"),
            contentType: 'image/png'
        } 
    } 
    imgModel.create(obj, (err, item) => { 
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err); 
        } 
        else { 
            res.redirect('/'); 
        } 
    }); 
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    imgModel.find({}, (err, items) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.render('app', { items }); // for an ejs
            res.send(items); // this code i use for vuejs, and delete the above line
        }
    })
})
```

EJS:

```html
<h1>Uplaoded Images</h1> 
    <div> 
        <% items.forEach(function(image) { %> 
        <div> 
            <div> 
                
                <% console.log(image.img.data) %>
                <img id="something" class="images" src="<%=image.img.data%>"> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
        <% }) %> 
    </div>
```

Vue Code:

```js
<template>
  <div>
      <li v-for="item in items" :key="item._id">
          <img :src="item.img.data" alt="">
      </li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name: 'ImageGallary',
    data() {
        return {
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            items: []

        }
    },
    async created() {
        await axios.get(this.url).catch(err => console.log(err)).then((res) => {
             this.items = res.data;
        });
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>%
```

Comment: `it works fine in .ejs file but not in Vue` - what breaks in vue? `make it visible as a image in Vue component but could not find any method` where have you looked?

Comment: I don't know but in ejs, it replaces the entire code with data by converting object to base64, but in Vue it show it as Object obj, I am sorry for vague answers but I am new to vue hence don't know much.

Comment: `it show it as Object obj` ... what is this `it` ... you're treating an Object as a String - perhaps you're *doing something wrong™* with the response in vue - no code, can only guess

Comment: I looked for vuejs blog for the same online, but did not find one. In those tuts(blogs) ejs is used or react but for Vue I did not find one.

Comment: I'm not asking you for blogs and tutorials, I'm asking you how YOU are handling the data currently where it results in `[Object object]` rather than what you expect - clearly you're getting something in a response, but you may just be handling it wrong, but without code, it's just speculation

Comment: above is what I did (sorry for not putting code previously), is there any way to show the image which is working fine in ejs to show in vue?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(res.data[0].img.data)` why are you stringifying the data? did you mean JSON.parse?

Comment: no sorry that was the last version of the code.

Comment: what is the exact content of `res.data` - also ... await AND .then in the same function is more often than not bad coding